# Check if (during insertion) building has always same adress

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger which validates data before insertion.

To simplify my problem: consider this as my insertion:

```
INSERT INTO Event 
VALUES ('A', 'building1', 'adress1'),
       ('B', 'building2', 'adress2'),
       ('C', 'building1', 'adress3')
```

I need to catch case in which INSERTED table contains same building with different addresses - which is not possible.

Some `IF` statement snippet would really help me here.

Comment: How about using a check constraint instead?

Comment: @JamesZ Sadly, using trigger is a requirement in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is provided by *Gordon*. If normalizing the structure is not an option, you can consider an `Unique Index` on combination of 2 columns `building, address`. If this is also not an option and you really need to create a trigger:

```
if exists(select building 
          from inserted 
          group by building 
          having count(distinct address) > 1)
begin
    --your logic here
end
```

Comment: I'd never think of distinct in "count(distinct address)". Good to know. Also - I totally agree with "best solution" part.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using triggers for this?  The issue is your data model.

If a building can have only one address, then you should have a table called `Buildings`:

```
create table Buildings (
    BuildingId int identity primary key,
    BuildingName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255)
);
```

Then, your `Events` table should refer to the `BuildingId`:

```
create table Events (
    EventId int identity primary key,
    EventName varchar(255) unique,
    BuildingId int references Buildings(BuildingId)
);
```

You shouldn't use triggers to get around a problem with the data model.

Comment: Tell that to my "assignment list". This is what happens when the exerice explicitly makes you write retarded solutions to simple problems. Also - question has been simplified. What I am actually doing is a "parent" table that when modified, should update its children - which look exactly like the tables you show here. I need validation on "parent" table level tho - thus my question.

Comment: @Ernio . . . There really are problems out there where an `instead of` trigger is a good idea.  It is sad when the developers of courses do not point out the right solution to problems.  I don't think students learn the material as well as they should.